# Can SQL Reporting services email a pdf?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, discountasp

I currently use www.discountasp.net for my web hosting. When a customer places an order I want to find a way that I can get a pdf version of the invoice to my local machine. The reason I want to do this is that I'd like to have a schedule task on my local machine that grabs all orders from the day at a specified time and print the pdf documents off ready for me to pack the goods. At the very worst I'd like to have them as attachments to emails sent to my machine.

I can see that SQL reporting can export to pdf so I'm assuming I can somehow pass an order id to a page that calls the SQL report to generate the invoice and send me the file. The other option is to store the invoice on the server and I'll create a script that logs in, copies it down, then clears it off. I've had 'slight' exposure to working with SQL Reports before but nothing along this line.

Has anyone got any experience with something like this that would know and possibly specific experience with it being hosted on discountasp.net to let me know if it's possible? Could you give me some advice on what to do or how to do it to solve my issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it can.

> Reporting Services includes an e-mail
>   delivery extension that provides a way
>   to e-mail a report to individual users
>   or groups. The e-mail delivery
>   extension is configured through the
>   Reporting Services Configuration tool
>   and by editing the Reporting Services
>   configuration files.

[E-Mail Delivery in Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160334.aspx)